# replace php function 'file' using curl

Tags: php, file, curl, fopen

how to replace php function 'file' using curl?

```
$ego_quote = file($egoUrl); nicely put into an array.

$ego_quote[0] = error=OK
$ego_quote[1] = eta=Overnight
$ego_quote[2] = price=56.44
```

how can i achieve this when i'm using CURL?

Reason, function 'fopen' which is related to function 'file' not available on our production server.

Thank you

Comment: cURL will return something more similar to [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents). You can then explode at newlines to achieve same effect as `file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Crayon Violent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184595/crayon-violent) in this post.

```
$ego_quote = explode("\n",$ego_quote);
```

Which will give you the same result as function `file`

```
$ego_quote[0] = error=OK
$ego_quote[1] = eta=Overnight
$ego_quote[2] = price=56.44
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $egoUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```